# How to add data to ListView from another page/class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, navigation

Ok, IM have few pages in dart/flutter, on third page I want to add data to list view witch is on the first page?
I have Model class like this:

```
class Doors_Model {
  final String image;
  final String name;
  final String desc;

  Doors_Model({this.image, this.name, this.desc});

  static List<Doors_Model> allDevices() {
    var listOfAllDoors = new List<Doors_Model>();

    listOfAllDoors.add(
        new Doors_Model(image: 'door.png', name: 'name', desc: 'description'));

    return listOfAllDoors;
  }
}
```

Lets just say in third class/page I have some data to pass with button click :
So when I click the button i need to populate list view base on the model...

```
class AddDevices extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddDevicesState createState() => _AddDevicesState();
}

class _AddDevicesState extends State<AddDevices> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      child: Material(   
         
          child: Scaffold(       
         

                        floatingActionButton : FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: (){

            _addDataToListView();

                }, elevation: 3,child: Icon(Icons.add),
              )
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

And on the listView page I have:

```
...
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final List<Doors_Model> _allDevices = Doors_Model.allDevices();
...
  Widget _getList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card( 
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: Image.asset(
              "assets/" + _allDevices[index].image,            
            ),
            title: Text(_allDevices[index].name),
            subtitle: Text(_allDevices[index].desc),
            trailing: Text('')          
             
              ),
            ),
          
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way for this, just use sharedpreference to save the data, read these data information from first page

Comment: thanks for suggestion, is there any other way coming to your mind..?